# Is it possible to change flushInterval value in myBatis's own cache implementation dynamically

Tags: orm, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

There are two scenarios where I want my flush interval to be 300000 (5 mins) and in some cases I dont want flush interval at all i.e. I want my cache to be constant throughout the session i.e. I want flush to be disabled and similarly if I release freeze it should again operate after every 5 mins.

```
                  <cache
                  eviction="FIFO"
                  flushInterval="300000"
                  size="512"
                  readOnly="true"/>


   <select id="getStoreIdAndEqId"  resultType="String" flushCache="false"  useCache="true">
           select count(author) from blog
        </select>
```

Technology I am using is MyBatis and Spring.

Comment: You can get the cache via the mapped statements, I suggest simply having a look at them, find out which class the cache is off and perhaps you'll find a method to change these values there.

Comment: I didn't get it completely. cache implementation worked fine to my mapped statements. But the problem is I want to flush the cache and change the flush interval as per my requirements at different stages of a single session. For eg: I want cache from now till beginning of time upon clicking a button and then I unclick the button and after 15 mins I again on that toggle button and now I want data from now+15 mins till beginning but what I get is just now till the beginning data.

Answer (score 1):

So, I have debugged a little and unfortunately, the answer to your question is... "kind of"...

When I use your cache configuration, then I get the following cache structure (by `Configuration.MappedStatement( ID ).Cache` ):

A `SynchronizedCache` that delegates the caching to a `LogingCache` that delegates the caching to a `ScheduledCache` that delegates the caching to a `FifoCache` that delegates the caching to a `PerpetualCache`. Every one of these delegates does a little bit of work (logging, etc.) and then delegates the rest.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no "normal" way to get the delegate of the `SynchronizedCache` and that class offers no way to modify the settings of underlying `Cache` objects. Of course you could use reflection to get them, but that's not a good idea. So, I don't see way to do so with the default caches.

Which leads us to the "kind of" answer... You can write your own `Cache` implementation, for example `MyCacheImpl`, to do the work and set it via...

```
<cache type="com.example.MyCacheImpl"/>
```

Unfortunately, it will be wrapped in a LoggingCache (that delegates to it) and, you guessed right, LoggingCache also doesn't offer a way to get the delegate. So you will probably have to do some workaround there, for example by registering the Caches in a static HashMap or something like this. Of course, this can easily open up a whole can of bugs, so tread carefully. When you do so, you can access your Caches directly and call any behaviour altering methods you want.

Comment: Thanks Florian that was helpful. Well on top of it I have one more question : suppose I have one more `<select id="getWholeData"  resultType="java.util.LinkedHashMap" flushCache="false" useCache="true"> select * from blog</select>` in the mapper tag. So in that case is it possible to just let `getStoreIdAndEqId` reference to existing `getWholeData` cache not hit db and get new data.

Comment: I've seen your issue on the tracker, but no, I do not think that's easily possible, since MyBatis has no way of knowing that the size of the list of your query A hat to be the Integer result of query B. MyBatis doesn't actually parse the queries, it just sends them. You could write a custom Cache implementation, but that seems overkill.

Comment: Ah! got it. That leads me to more issues with performance at stake. Can I have your mail or something so that I can send detail of my issue I think I would be needing some architectural advice.

Comment: While I have no problem trying to help you (see me profile for a link to my hp or twitter), the idea of this site is to make answers, etc. public so it might be a good idea to ask these questions here or on one of the sister sites.

Comment: Yes I got it but I thought may be it would be vague to rest and may be lengthy :)

Comment: In this case, feel free.